# Change font size enumeration

Tags: fontsize, fancyhdr

I have the following LaTeX code to format page numbers:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}     
\fancyheadoffset{0mm}
\fancyfootoffset{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\thepage}}
\setcounter{page}{5}
```

They work well with using the default font size. I want to change the font size (using `\Large`) with the following code:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\Large\thepage}       
\fancyheadoffset{0mm}
\fancyfootoffset{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
    \Large
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\thepage}}
\setcounter{page}{5}
```

The changes in size are only visible on pages following the starting page of the chapter.

Comment: Starting pages of chapters use the plain style, you have to define the pagenumber as `\Large` there, too.

`\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\Large\thepage}}`

Comment: I tried use your solution, but it do not work. When i define the pagenumber i get a lot of errors.

Comment: You should define headers/footers in the preamble. If you *really* have to set page numbers, this is done in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapters in reports and books start a new page with the page style `plain`. If you want to change the font size there as well, you have to modify the plain style.

You should define headers and footers in the preamble of your document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\Large\thepage}       
\fancyheadoffset{0mm}
\fancyfootoffset{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
    \Large
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\Large\thepage}
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\setcounter{page}{1}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Setting page numbers by hand is a dangerous activity, as this can lead to *wrong* page numbers. Please be aware, that this in only done in the document, i.e. after `\begin{document}`.